# блок в виде дуги

Tags: css3

как создать такой блок?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, тут бы больше подошло использование или **canvas**, или **svg**, но если css3, то можно [таким способом попробовать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wtS44/) (то же самое, но [значения в процентах](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/wtS44/1/)).

Answer (score 1):

Пользуй border-radius. Как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/MgMEr/